# Changing background color of form field affects size and style

Tags: html, css

I am seeing potentially strange behavior of web forms when modifying them via CSS.

I have the following HTML code of a simple web form:

```css
.email {
  background-color: #FFFEEE;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Us</legend>
    Name:
    <p>
      <input class="name" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Name">
    </p>
    E-Mail:
    <p>
      <input class="email" type="text" size="30" placeholder="john@doe.com">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Just in case, here is a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sge13t9r/3/

However, as in the picture below, while I only specified a background color, the size and style of the field changed as well. The browser used is Firefox. Can anyone please advise on the reasons for such behavior and how I should go about just changing the background color, without affecting the size and style?

[image: Result of CSS]

Fiddle Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: In your fiddle the inputs look the same except the background. Maybe you dont recognize the default `border-style: inset` on the white input. In Your screenshot are defenetly some other styles applied.

Comment: That's the thing, I did not explicitly apply any other styles and the screenshot is from the fiddle window itself. May I ask what browser you are using? Perhaps it is a compatibility issue for me.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're describing in Firefox or Chrome. Both fine. But from your image and your first input field it looks like you're using some other CSS for styling

Comment: Do you have some extension? I think lastpass adds a strange yellow background, maybe something else is messing with the styles.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added another screenshot to show that I'm not using any additional styling on the "name" input field. But based on what you see, I think perhaps this something to do with my default Firefox settings. I just checked this on Opera and there was no difference in style there. Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell you the reason why, but I can confirm that as soon as you start modyfying just one property of a text input field, the whole input field (except the one added parameter) is "reset" to some very old looking default style, including inset border, grey background and other things. I'd be interested too what's the "logic" behind that.

Comment: @Johannes Good thing to know I'm not the only one with this question. Thanks! If I ever come across anything about this I'll post it back here so we'll both know.

Answer (score 1):

Your name input is definitely getting a default padding from the Firefox browser. What you need to do is specify the padding for inputs and use the box sizing property. This is the CSS you should have:

```
.email {
    background-color: #FFFEEE;
}
input {
    padding: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```